# How to easily visualize reference IDs?

Tags: bibtex

I have about two hundred bibtex references in my document. Sometimes I am browsing the references section and find something that I want to use again. Let's say there is an item like the following:

```
[45] Smith, John. Whatever paper, 2013
```

The problem is then which ID should I use in order to add another reference to the same paper? There are two ways to include such reference again:

1. Search for "Whatever paper" in the bibtex file and see that the ID is "`smith2013.blablabla`".
2. Search for [45] on the generated PDF file, then find a text like "`according to Smith [45]`", then go to the TEX file and find "`according to Smith \cite{smith2013.blablabla}`".

This is obviously time consuming. It would be much better to see those IDs on the exported references:

```
[45] [smith2013.blablabla] Smith, John. Whatever paper, 2013
```

I only want to see this while I am writing the document, so it should be easy to remove those IDs when I generate the final version.

Comment: This could help you http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showkeys

Comment: related: [showlabels: wrap labels in marginpar](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60693/579).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I print the cite key along with the entire `.bib` file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51161/5764)

Comment: Thanks. showkeys almost solves my problem. I have to use a conference template that does not leave much space between text and margin, so I can't see the whole keys as half of each label is out of the paper.

Comment: Thanks. showkeys almost solves my problem. I have to use a conference template that does not leave much space between text and margin, so I can't see the whole keys as half of each label is out of the paper.